# JNI Use native method

Tags: java, dll, methods, java-native-interface

I'm working on a project where there's the need to call some methods from dll files. 
These two dlls are

- EasySign.dll
- EasySignJNI

EasySignJNI depends on EasySign.

I wrote the class to load EasySignJNI as follows:

```
package easysign;


class EasySign {

    EasySign(){}

    public native String EasyHashFile(String filename);
    public native int EasySign(String pkcs11_driver,String pin, int type, String file_data, int out_format, String signed_file, String cert_out, int cert_format);
    public native int EasyVerify(String cert_user, String file_data, String signed_file, String crl_file, String ca_file, String out_document);


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("EasySignJNI");
    }
 }
```

Now I would call these method from my main method like this:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
          EasySign es = new EasySign();
          System.out.println("EasyHashFile : " + es.EasyHashFile("test.txt"));
        }
    }
```

What I have to specify in the `-Djava.library.path` ? Only the path where my EasySignJNI.dll is located? It is possible to call native method in this way?
I'm using NetBeans for completeness.

EDIT: 
I have noticed that the third party dll provided to me (the JNI dll in particular) defines method names without any package, so I'm forced to put the class that loads the dll in the default package. Is there any way to change only the dll method names including my own package name?

EDIT 2:
What I mean is that both EasySign.dll and EasySignJNI.dll are provided me as they are and I can't modify them (I have not the source code). The EasySignJNI is the JNI portion but inspecting it I have noticed thath the method sign is in the form: _java_EasySign_MethodName. When I load the dll in Java from my Easysign class (this class must reside in the "mypackage" package), I receive the jni unsatisfiedlinkerror because, if I understood right, I'm calling the "_java_mypackage_EasySign_MethodName" method, i.e the sign is different from the dll's one. So the only way to make it work is to rewrite the JNI part and build it to have the correct sign of the JNI method?

Answer (score 0):

> What I have to specify in the -Djava.library.path ? Only the path where my EasySignJNI.dll is located?

Correct, the operating system will locate the dependent EasySign.dll for you as long as it is available where the OS expects it to be.

> It is possible to call native method in this way? I'm using NetBeans for completeness.

I read through your edit and you have successfully lost me.  What default package are you referring to?  (Remember that none of us know what EasySign.dll is)  So, I am going to provide some info about how I do what you originally described and hopefully it will help.

First start by compiling EasySign if you have the src.  Do not build a DLL or shared object, instead build a static library.  If you do not have the src code for EasySign, or a prebuilt static library, you will be stuck with the dll and can continue to the next step.

Now you are ready to compile the jni portion.  All of your JNI C code should basically translate your Java input/output to their JVM/Native types and call the appropriate functions in the DLL library.  You want to keep this layer and thin and simple as possible because it is incredibly difficult to debug.  Your C++ package names shouldn't really matter here and you can use what ever package name you want for your Java classes.  You should be able to compile the JNI code and preferably static link to the EasySign.dll file so you don't need to worry about distributing it.  If you must dynamically link, make sure EasySign.dll gets installed to a location that is on the [DLL PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) / [LDPATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80) because the OS will need to locate and load that file right after the JVM loads the JNI DLL.

At this point you should just be able to point -Djava.library.path at your JNI DLL's path and all should work.

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the unclarity! I've edited the question to try to make it more clear!

Comment: Thanks for the update!  That does clarify quite a bit!  If EasySignJNI is provided to you, they must also provide you the JAR that contains the native method declarations they used to build the JNI library.  Unfortunately, you cannot modify the native method signatures after the library is compiled.  So to answer your question; yes, you must recompile the JNI portion to change the package name.